# How do I make an if statement only return true when another if statement has already happened?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

Okay, this is probably a dumb question but I'm new to this. I have an enemy AI that walks toward the player only when the enemy is visible to the player and the space key is pressed. I want to make a second if statement that makes the enemy run if the player presses the space bar a second time while the enemy is walking or if the enemy is within 2 meters of the of the players current position.

```
{
    public NavMeshAgent enemy;
    public Transform player;

    public float speedWalk = 6f;
    public float speedRun = 60f;
    public float groundDrag;
    public float playerHeight;

    bool isWalking;


    Renderer m_Renderer;

    void Move(float speed)
    {
        enemy.speed = speed;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        isWalking = false;
        enemy.speed = speedWalk;
    }

    private void OnBecomeInvisible()
    {
        enabled = false;
    }

    //DelayEnemyChase
    IEnumerator delayChase()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        Move(speedWalk);
        enemy.SetDestination(player.position);
    }

    //Visible by camera
    void OnBecameVisible()
    {
        enabled = true;
        
        //starts walking towards player position
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) && (m_Renderer.isVisible) && (isWalking == false))
        {
            StartCoroutine(delayChase());
            isWalking = true;
        }

       //starts walking towards player position
        else if ((isWalking == true) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) && (m_Renderer.isVisible))
        {
            Move(speedRun);
            enemy.SetDestination(player.position);
            isWalking = false;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
            //sees if enemy is visible + space bar is pressed
            OnBecameVisible();
    }

}
```

This is confusing the heck out of me, this is what I have and it's not workign at all. Any help is appreciated!!!!

Comment: keep a variable that says that other thing happened.

Comment: Once he's in view of the enemy can he become out of view again?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `GetKey` is fired every frame as long as the button stays pressed!

You rather want to use `GetKeyDown` in order to track only the first key press.

Then you currently also start and run multiple concurrent Coroutines!

I would rather use a kind of state routine and do e.g.

```
private void OnBecomeInvisible()
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
    enemy.enabled = false;
}

private void OnBecameVisible()
{
    enemy.enabled = true;
    Move(0f);
    enemy.SetDestination(enemy.transform.position);
    StartCoroutine (StatesRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator StatesRoutine ()
{
    // wait until the space is pressed the first time
    // here it depends on what exactly you want to do
    // you can either already track if the key is still pressed already
   yield return new WaitUntil (() => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space));
   // or rather wait until the key goes down the first time after having become visible
   //yield return new WaitUntil (() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));

   yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
   Move(speedWalk);
   enemy.SetDestination(player.position);

   // Then for the second press we definitely wait until it gets down again instead of 
   // only checking if the button is still pressed
   // except again your use case actually wants that behavior
   yield return new WaitUntil (() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));
    
    
   Move(speedRun);
   enemy.SetDestination(player.position);
}
```

Some things still depend on your exact needs though, in particular what shall happen if the enemy becomes invisible. For now I assume you wanted to reset the behavior and start the process of handling space clicks from scratch.